# Select records where not in relational table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables with this structures :

```
**table1**
id   |  title
-----+--------
 1   |  Blah1
 2   |  Blah2

**table2**
id   |  table1_id  | article_id
-----+-------------+------------
 1   |   1         |  1
 2   |   1         |  3
 3   |   2         |  1
```

Now I want to know how can I select all records from `table1` where not use in `table2`

for example I need all `table1` records where not exists in `table2` for `article_id=3`

How can I create model and use eloquent models ?

**UPDATE:**

I need `Blah2` from `table1` and then show to my user, because `Blah1` inserted for `article_id = 3` before.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is worked query, I need write model for this query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 AS a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT table1_id
FROM table2
WHERE article_id = 3
)
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more precisely what you're looking for ? If you can't at least update your question and design a schema for your expected output like you already gave for table1 and table2.

Comment: @MahfuzulAlam I updated my question

Comment: @MajAfy : Do you want to get  records from table 1  whose id is not available in table 2 as article_id field . Means you want 

id   |    title 
-----------------
2   |    Blah2

Because 2 is not available as article_id in table 2 , right ?

Comment: @DeepakDixit Yes, exactly

Comment: @DeepakDixit I added a sample query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create model something like below you can change name appropriately
here i will refer something like below
table1 => ParentModel and table2 => ChildModel

define relation for children in ParentModel with below method

```
class ParentModel extends Model {
    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(ChildModel::class, 'table1_id');
    }
}
```

whereDoesntHave method is available to filter records with related model
check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

```
ParentModel::whereDoesntHave('children', function($q){
     // here $q refers to related model in this case ChildModel
     $q->where('article_id', 3); 
})->get();
```

above query should return the required results.